# Matplotlib style sheet not being applied

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I've been trying several style sheets but none of them seems to be applied to the canvas. This is the first time I'm using `twinx()` so maybe that's the issue. The code I have tried is below -

```
import pickle
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

with open("acc.pkl", "rb") as a:
    acc = pickle.load(a)

with open("loss.pkl", "rb") as b:
    loss = pickle.load(b)

x = np.array([point for point in range(100)])

fig, graph_1 = plt.subplots()
points_1 = np.array(acc)
graph_1.plot(x, points_1, 'b')

graph_2 = graph_1.twinx()
points_2 = np.array(loss)
graph_2.plot(x, points_2, 'r')

plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')
plt.xlabel('epochs')
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stylesheet parameters are applied at the time the object that uses them is *created*.

E.g. if you want to have a figure and axes in a given style, you need to set the style sheet **before** creating them via `plt.subplots`.

```
plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')
fig, graph_1 = plt.subplots()
```